# install dotnet upgrade-assistant tool - offline

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, migrate, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to install the **upgrade-assistant** migration tool on a PC that has no internet connection , but getting an error since it's trying to access *nuget.org* unsuccessfully.

the error i'm getting is:

> Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I could download files on another PC and copy them to that machine, i did see the [github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant) for the tool, but not i'm sure what files to dowload and to how actually run the install.

any help is welcome

TIA

Comment: Everything in .NET is pulled from NuGet and hence, the internet. You won't be able to develop anything without internet connectivity. That's not a recent development either. For the last 10 years even BCL libraries are released through NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Install it on the other PC.
2. Locate your `.dotnet/tools` directory on the other PC. (On my Windows machine it's here: `C:\Users\Frank\.dotnet\tools` )
3. And then copy that folder tools over to the other PC, after locating the `.dotnet/tools` directory there.
4. Make sure you are not forgetting the `./dotnet/tools/.store` contents. And also make sure you don't overwrite stuff.

Comment: Even that won't be enough. It will be enough to download a tool but not enough to restore NuGet packages. The tool itself may need to download new packages